# How to activate core 1 and 2 on AURIX TriCore microcontrollers?

Tags: c, microcontroller, multicore, infineon

I'm new to programming TriCore MCUs. I am trying to get a program running on all the three cores of the MCU. I am using the TC277 TriBoard and the HighTec Free Entry toolchain with the Universal Debug Engine.
Here is the code I am using:

```
int main()
{
    switch (__mfcr(CPU_CORE_ID))
    {
        case 0:
        {
            main_Core0();
            break;
        }

        case 1:
        {
            main_Core1();
            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {
            main_Core2();
            break;
        }
    }

    return (0);
}
```

When I start debugging i see that only Core0 is running while Core 1 and 2 remain "inactive". Can someone explain me why aren't they running and how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Is a compiler available to you which supports openmp?

Comment: I didn't find any that would work with Infineon MCUs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal behaviour of AURIX that after system start only core 0 is running.
Normally, your compiler's startup code is responsible for activating the other cores. Check your compiler documentation on how to do that. I don't use the Hitech toolchain myself, so I can't help you with that.

If you have to activate the cores by yourself, you have to write the value 2 to HALT field of the core's Debug Status Register DBGSR:

```
CPUx_DBGSR.B.HALT=2;
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I also had to set the Program Counter to the _start label to make it execute code

Comment: In multicore Tricore systems, what core registers are shared and which are core-specific (like CORE_ID)?